# How to filtered data with useSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Language used : JS with REACT REDUX

Here is the context: I have a page where the user can see all the forms made.

At the initialization of my application, I dispatch 'get forms'. this dispatch allows me via axios to retrieve all the forms I have in db

```
useEffect(() => { 
    dispatch(getForms());
  }, []);
```

i have an action and reducer file :

actions

```
import axios from "axios";

export const GET_ALL_FORMS = "GET_ALL_FORMS";
  
export const getForms = () => (dispatch) =>
  axios
    .get(`/api/form`)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: GET_ALL_FORMS, payload: res.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => err);
```

reducer

```
import { GET_ALL_FORMS } from "../actions/forms.actions";
  
const initialState = [];

export default function allFormsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_FORMS:
      return action.payload;
 
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then in my "folder" page I use 'useSelector' to retrieve all the forms and display them (working).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"; 

export const FolderNew = () => {
  const formData = useSelector((state) => state.allFormsReducer);
```

But now, at the click of a button, I would like to sorted my forms by date

Normally I don't use redux, so I would just do an axios request in my folder page and then use 'useState' (allForms, setAllForms) with my res.data and refresh the state like this :

```
  const descend  = () => {
    const sorted = [...allForms].sort((a, b) =>
      b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt)
    );
    setAllForms(sorted); 
  };
```

But now, with redux i'm really lost.

What i'm actually trying : Change the reducer to sort here the state (not working for the moment)

Comment: You should make a change to the state in the store, meaning you should create an action that returns a sorted version of the array. You then dispatch that action on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dispatch action something like `sortForms()`, then write the logic in your reducer:

```
export default function allFormsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SORT_ALL_FORMS': {
     const sortedForms = ....

     return sortedForms
    }
  }
}
```

As Redux documents state, you should put as much logic as possible in your reducers:

https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers